# Cannot clone object ' does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I have:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, KFold

# Extract the main and side frequency factors concentractions and catalyst concentrations from the data
main_freq_factors = np.array(FreqFac['Main frequency factors concentraction (l/(mol*s))'])
side_freq_factors = np.array(FreqFac['Side frequency factors concentraction (1/s)'])
catalyst_conc = np.array(FreqFac.iloc[:,1].values)

# Scale the data using the min-max scaler
main_freq_factors_scaled = minmax_scale(main_freq_factors)
side_freq_factors_scaled = minmax_scale(side_freq_factors)
catalyst_conc_scaled = minmax_scale(catalyst_conc)

# Combine the scaled data into a single array
X = catalyst_conc_scaled
y = np.column_stack((main_freq_factors_scaled, side_freq_factors_scaled))


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Xsc, Ysc, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

# Define the model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))

# Compile the model with the mean squared error loss function and Adam optimization algorithm
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

# Define the grid of hyperparameters to search
param_grid = {
    'epochs': [50, 100, 150],
    'batch_size': [32, 64, 128]
}

# Create a K-fold cross-validation generator
kfold = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

# Create a grid search object using the model, param_grid, and kfold
grid_search = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid, cv=kfold, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', return_train_score=True)

# Fit the grid search object to the data
grid_search.fit(catalyst_conc.reshape(-1, 1), main_freq_factors)

# Print the results of the grid search
print(grid_search.best_params_)
```

But I get the error:

```
Cannot clone object '<keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x7eff87f72580>' (type <class 'keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'>): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The error comes from scikit's [`clone`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/affaa62b1d053f3349e766aee91f397267a72656/sklearn/base.py#L79-L84) which is used by `GridSearchCV` (through [`BaseSearchCV`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/209c13278649eb0167d8a8506f586e30684997a0/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L810)) to create a separate copy of the estimator for each parameter configuration during the grid search.

You could try using a [wrapper for the Scikit-Learn API](https://faroit.com/keras-docs/2.1.5/scikit-learn-api/):

```py
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor

# ...

def build_fn():
  # Define the model
  model = tf.keras.Sequential()
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,)))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))

  # Compile the model with the mean squared error loss function and Adam optimization algorithm
  model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
  return model

model = KerasRegressor(build_fn)

# ...
```

Another option is to `pip install` [`scikeras`](https://www.adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/migration.html) and replace the import above with:

```py
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
```